# facebook comments plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website where people can register and login.

I have put the facebook comments in their loggedon page, so other people can post comments.

(from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)

Trouble is : all comments are mixed for all users.
Is it possible to have only comments for eached user, **so 1 user can only see comments about himself and not comments about other users** ?

regards

Answer (score 1):

I think it is posible. For each user you will need to set a different url like so:

```
<fb:comments href="http://www.example.com/user.html?userid=123" num_posts="2" width="500"></fb:comments>
```

Try it : ]